# Can we use include on extension points as the diagram shows

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am making a use case to present 2 FA process for my desktop application where the user will be required to either choose a secret question or SMS code for 2FA.

Is it correct to include extension points to show the login process?

This is what I have created so far [image: My Use case Diagram]

Comment: These are not use cases but functions. I think you better use an activity diagram or a sequence diagram to show this typo of behavior.

Comment: As Geert says. Start over with an AD. The above is (I'd guess) (a part of) a payment transaction inside the use case "Pay Drink".

Comment: I recommend (as always) to read Bittner/Spence about use cases.

Comment: I voted to close this question as too broad since it's targeting basics of UC synthesis that just fill a book.

Comment: How is too broad @qwerty_so I'm asking specifically is including extention points correct or incorrect basing on the diagram shown?

Comment: Why did you delete your answer was it incorrect? @qwerty_so

Comment: Your question does not make any sense since you did not get the very basics.

Comment: The title of your question is: "Can we use include on extension points". I don't understand this title. Do you mean "Can we use an ≪include≫ relationship from use case A to use case B, if use case A has extension points" ? In the question description, you ask a different question: "Is it correct to include extension points to show the login process". Do you mean "Is it allowed to have a main use case 'Log in' which delegates some parts to other use cases, extending the main use case at specific extension points"? The title and the description seem to refer to two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether your diagram is a valid UML diagram: Yes, it is valid, except for two minor details:

1. Extend should begin with a lowercase letter e;
2. The name of the use case should be separated from the list of extension points by a horizontal line from one end of the ellipse to the other.

If you want to know whether it is correct according to some methodology, please specify which methodology you use. In general, use case text books strongly discourage the use of include and extend like you do, because each use case should give some added value to an actor, instead of being a small piece of functionality.

Comment: I would dare to put it stronger and say the use cases such as "Display login error" are not use cases by the UML definition. The UML specs states about use cases **it specifies a set of behaviors performed by that subject, which yields an observable result that is of value for Actors or other stakeholders of the subject.** I don't really see the "set of behaviors" or the "observable result that is of value for Actors" in a use case called "Display login error"

Comment: I agree and I considered answering in that way, but in the end, I didn't for two reasons: (1) whether a use case like 'Display login error' yields a result of value to an Actor is open to debate, although I would answer 'no'; (2) the question is specifically about the use of extension points, so I decided to focus on that aspect.